# AWS Cognito Mock

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, hapi.js, amazon-cognito

I want to write BDD tests for my nodejs based API which uses AWS cognito as user authentication service, but I don't want to hit the real cognito service every time my build runs.

Is there an easy and elegant way to mock Cognito calls.

## Used frameworks :

- Nodejs (Hapi.js)
- aws-sdk for nodejs

Comment: Amazon Cognito is not a user authentication service. For writing your tests you can use any of the popular mocking libraries to mock the Cognito Client.

Comment: Cognito validate your token against facebook, g+ ... so it is a kind of authentication when you send your token.
I know that there are a bunch of popular libs. My question is about the better way to mock aws-cognito that I am not aware of

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We have created an [aws-sdk-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk-mock) npm module which mocks out all the AWS SDK services and methods.  https://github.com/dwyl/aws-sdk-mock

It's really easy to use. Just call AWS.mock with the service, method and a stub function.

```
AWS.mock('CognitoIdentityServiceProvider', 'theCallYouWantToMock', function(params, callback) {
    callback(null, 'success');
});
```

Then restore the methods after your tests by calling:

```
AWS.restore('CognitoIdentityServiceProvider', 'theCallYouWantToMock');
```

Comment: Nice, did it work also for DynamoDB.DocumentClient ?

Comment: @amgohan it works for every service and method in the aws-sdk.

Answer (score 0):

How did you end up mocking the Cognito Service? I don't see any documentation.

Is it something like

`AWS.mock('COGNITO', params, callback);`